# `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found Centos7

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, apache-2.4, centos7

while starting deepstream output show like this how can i resolve this issue. I installed the latest version which is not available in yum repo by using rpm file and i can't remove this package too..shows the same error. please help

deepstream: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by deepstream)
deepstream: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by deepstream)
deepstream: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by deepstream)

Comment: Which "deepstream" is this? What RPM?

Comment: deepstream server v3.2.4.........websocket server that syncs realtime data

Comment: https://github.com/deepstreamIO/deepstream.io/releases

Comment: https://deepstreamhub.com/open-source/

Comment: Did you follow the [instructions](https://deepstream.io/install/centos/index.html)?

Comment: actually 3.2.4 is not in yum repository, so i download the rpm file and install via command

Comment: Use 'ldd' on the given bin and find the missing libs. Then you either need to find the .so for it and place it in some place the bin can see it.

Answer (score 1):

This was most likely built on a different OS version, one that had a newer version of gcc/g++/libstdc++

You can either chase down a newer version of libstdc++ and put it somewhere that your app can find it (using LD_LIBRARY_PATH) or build from source.

Personally I’d not chase this stuff down and I’d run it under docker. There seems to be an official image at https://hub.docker.com/r/deepstreamio/deepstream.io/